# Fonts are not rendering on Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, browser

I've made a website with some custom font , Opensans .. it's actually worked fine in all browsers including firefox , but suddenly fonts not appearing in the site , it shows me a default font size , but this issue is only in firefox . and the site is developing under local host . what's the wrong ? and all css and fonts everything is fine .

Comment: Would you be able to show some of your code? I.e. the parts where you're importing and/or setting the `font-family`?

Comment: It would be difficult to triage the issue without seeing your code, but one thing you can do is to Inspect Element (right click on the part which is incorrectly rendered and select Inspect Element from the context menu). This will show you the HTML structure and besides that the CSS rules applied to that element. This will help you in determining why the intended rules are not being applied.

Also, check the Console for any CSS errors.